# Windows 2003 network connection unexpected error

Tags: windows-server-2003

All of the sudden on our Windows 2003 server we can't access NIC settings. When choosing
Network Connections/NIC1/Properties we get Unexpected error has occurred. Can't change NIC IP or gateway.

Comment: Fix All approach - Have you rebooted the server?

Comment: Yes, rebooted twice. Also tried
regsvr32 netshell.dll
regsvr32 ole32.dll

Comment: Is the NIC working with its current config?  In other words, is the NIC physically toasted?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried disabling and re-enabling it, or uninstalling/reinstalling it in Device Manager?  (From Device Manager, uninstalled and then re-detect it?)

-Waldo